# Oracle table type passing data table from c# application

Tags: c#, oracle

Hello all I am trying to insert data to oracle table by passing the data table data to my procedure in oracle. For that I have created a table type and object type as follows

```
create or replace TYPE EMP_CSV_OBJ AS OBJECT 
(
    FirstName VARCHAR2(50),
    LastName VARCHAR2(50),
    MiddleName VARCHAR2(50)
);

create or replace TYPE EMP_CSV_TABLE 
AS TABLE OF emp_csv_obj;
```

I have create one proc as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_EMPLOYEE(empCsv IN EMP_CSV_TABLE) AS
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO Employee pt
  USING empCsv src
  ON (pt.FIRSTNAME = src.FIRSTNAME)
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 
  (pt.FIRSTNAME, pt.LASTNAME, pt.MIDDLENAME) 
  VALUES (ps.FirstName , ps.LastName , ps.MIDDLENAME);
  
  COMMIT;
END;
```

I have used the following code in my c# application

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt .Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
dt .Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
dt .Columns.Add("MiddleName", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add("AALI", "THOR", "R");
dt.Rows.Add("Dereanna", "CARTER", "Michelle");

string connectionString = "myconstring";
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();
   using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT_EMPLOYEE", connection))
   {
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter();
     param.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Array;
     param.UdtTypeName = "EMP_CSV_TABLE";
     param.Value = dt; 
     cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
 }
```

But I am getting the exception as `Invalid parameter binding`. I am new to oracle, so can some one help me here what I am doing wrong.